# Post photo (base64) to Facebook graph api using ajax

Tags: ajax, facebook, post, base64, multipartform-data

i am using straight up ajax to post a photo to facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos

I can post the photo fine if i use the url parameter. No problem. If i attempt to use the source parameter with a valid base64 image URI i get "#324 Requires upload file".

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos",
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
              source: base64ImageRef,
              message: "test yo!",
              access_token: mytoken                                                                        
    },
    success: function (result) {
         app.showAlert("Post response (facebook):" + result);
    },
    error: function (e) {
         app.showAlert(e);
    }
});
```

base64ImageRef looks like

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

i've tried with and without the  data:image/png;base64,

i've also tried %7B + base64ImageRef + %7D

i've tried changing the contentType to multipart/form-data

Stumped.. thanks.

Comment: The source parameter does not take a base64 string. You have to send it as multipart/form-data.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea how that's done with $.ajax ? thanks.

Comment: If you can get the image data as a blob rather than base64 string, you can use a formdata object.